# How to Upload File Using AWS-SDK (From Base64)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Example code in here:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fixNameFile = "tes.png";
let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
  endpoint: "xxx...",
  accessKeyId: "xxx...",
  secretAccessKey: "xxx...",
});
var imgBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,xxxxxx....";
var params = {
                 Bucket: 'fileupload',
                 ACL: 'public-read',
                 Key: fixNameFile,
                 Body: imgBase64,
                 ContentEncoding: 'base64'
             };
s3bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

In my case, this was uploaded successfully. However, only blank images like this appear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FenW2.jpg

does anyone have an idea from my case? Please help me :)

Comment: Why are you uploading base64?  Why not just send the binary?

Comment: because on request using base64 (on my team). Can you help me with that?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense though.  You want a binary image... and yet you're wasting 33% overhead in bandwidth and storage, and some extra CPU and memory on both the sending end and receiving end.  (Not to mention, this is why you can't use the file later... because you base64 encoded it without decoding.)

Comment: oh ok, It seems like this should be discussed with my partner. Thank you for the advice, it's very useful :) .